# Xargs to cd for files with spaces on mac

Tags: bash, xargs, cd, fzf

I have referred to quite a few answers on SO but haven't been able to figure out a solution for this.

What I am trying to do is to have a cd command that uses `fzf` to match the directory to jump into. I have been successful in implementing it with the following -

```bash
cd "$(find * -type d | fzf)"  # Works exactly as expected
```

However, I have been trying to see if the same behavior can be done by using `xargs` instead of a subshell. **The challenge is the files can have spaces in them.**

I have tried the following (after referring to multiple SO answers) but can't seem to figure out why this command silently fails.

```bash
find * -type d | fzf | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -t -0 cd  # Silently fails
```

I need help with the following -

1. Analyzing why the command runs but does nothing (silently fails)
2. An approach to pass the path (with spaces) to xargs cd

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Changing the directory in a subshell has no effect on the calling shell.

Comment: right, but i am not trying to run cd in a subshell. I need it to run on the shell as the final command

Comment: With `… | cd`, `cd` runs in a subshell.

Comment: ah ok, so there is no way to run cd with xargs then right? since xargs works after the pipe to pick the stdout from previous command?

Comment: Use other ways to import data to `xargs`, so it can be on top-level itself, e.g. `xargs < <(…)` would bringing only the pipeline with `find`, `fzf`, etc. into a subshell.

Comment: ok that makes sense. yea so i guess the better way to do this is the original method that I have been using. thanks this clarifies a lot! could you clarify the last example with the < usage?

Comment: I'm also struggling to understand why you need `xargs` in the first place. Do you want to change to multiple directories in succession? You don't even allow `fzf` to select multiple items.

Comment: no i dont need `fzf -m`, only need it for fuzzy matching a single path and then jumping to it. There might be few additional operations that i might want to add in the pipeline, which is why the xargs in the pipeline structure is appealing to me.

Comment: But `xargs` operates on multiple inputs, and is not necessary for having multiple outputs / actions (based on just one input).

Comment: `xargs` really isn't the right thing to use to change the directory of the current shell session because of how shell environments and subprocesses work. Even if `xargs` successfully changes directories in the subshell, this change won't affect your current shell session. You'd be better off creating a function that does what you want.

Comment: ok this clarifies a lot, thanks a ton to both!

Comment: For example `fcd() { local dir=$(find * -type d | fzf) if [[ -n "$dir" ]]; then cd "$dir" || return  fi }`

Comment: I expect an error message like `xargs: cd: No such file or directory`.